# ClassName obj =new ClassName(this); why this is used?

Tags: android

On the Android Developers website, to create new text view the following code is used:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

Why this is used?

Why can't an object for a textView simply be created like this?

```
TextView textView = new TextView();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with programming in `C`?

Comment: Because the TextView instance needs a handle to the object where it was created.

Comment: So it is wrong to create like this?

Comment: TextView textView = new TextView();

Comment: Well yes, that is wrong because It requires the `Context` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView does not have a no-argument constructor. None of Android's UI widgets have that. They all at least take a Context. The `this` in your post is probably an Activity, which extends Context.

You cannot call a no-arg constructor for a class which does not have one. It only has one if the author declared one, or if the author declared no constructors (in which case the compiler will add the no-arg constructor).

Comment: Your answer is simply explaining Java classes.  His question is regarding why the Android SDK requires a `Context`.

Comment: Yeah, why the Android SDK requires a Context

Comment: Because it needs one. There are any number of reasons why, most notably because it needs access to Resources, which is obtained through a Context.

Comment: If there is a class that does not need an argument to its constructor like TextView.

Comment: Then  is it okay to do like this?  ClassName obj =new ClassName();

Comment: Yes, but now we're back to explaining basic Java.

Comment: This website is great!